Basically vertical creek side bank collapse northern Utah
After a record mountain snowfall last spring, we lost a 30' long 10' wide chunk of our creek bank along with a couple of trees. I am getting a temporary workaround put in for next spring. We are on the outside curve of the creek going from north back to west, normally 6" deep but last year the runoff sent the creek up to about 5' for 3 1/2 months May-June. The runoff was really fast being the water's coming from 9800' mountain peaks to our east 4 miles away. I am left with a horseshoe shaped cutout with a straight vertical wall. The big problem with this is that the soil is just a loamy-sandy soil that pretty much washes away with any current.
For now, we are getting 3-4' boulders around the bottom of the washed out area and around the current banks on each end to keep the heaviest runoff away as much as can be done. We live about 4800' along the northern Wasatch front and the area is very shaded so I would like to see what would be good to erosion protection plants above the drop-off and if it would be prudent to plant anything in the drop-off. I was wondering if pushing seeds and sprouts of good plants into the side of the drop-off would be any help.

Have you worked with a hydrologist or engineer on your project? If there is nothing to slow down the flow during the spring melt upstream of your land, the full force of the water will be directed against the outer wall of that bed, hit those boulders and can easily move them - I've seen it happen during flash floods where I used to live. Another consideration could be trout - in my state, what you're planning is highly illegal if that is a recognized trout stream - fines and "put it back the way it was" are the norm here. Definitely NOT cheap!

Yup, check your legalities and whether you're just making it worse later on the one hand, and make sure that any miracle plants that someone might suggest are not regulated invasive/noxious weed plants in your area. Extension ( https://extension.usu.edu ) specialists may well be able to help or guide you to people who can help. If you have buildings above the eroded area, look into moving them before it erodes more and eats them.
